# How to create sentences from a list of words in a file

Tags: python

I have a list of words in a `csv` file, each word on a separate line. I want to read 15 lines and concatenate them into a sentence and then write them to a new `csv` file. Then repeat the process for the next 15 lines and add the new sentence on a new line till all words are utilized.

I have been able to create a list of words in the but since I am new to python I have no idea on how to loop through every given number of lines and concatenate a sentence into a new file.

Would appreciate any help.

I used the following code to create a list of words from a file which had a lot of text in it:

```
with open("outfile11.csv", encoding = 'UTF_8') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            print(word)
            with open("words.csv","a", encoding = 'UTF_8') as f1:
                f1.write(word + "\n")
```

Then I used the following code to remove any blank lines from the created list file:

```
with open("words.csv","r", encoding='UTF_8') as f, open("cleanedWords.csv","w", encoding='UTF_8') as outfile:
 for i in f.readlines():
       if not i.rstrip():
           continue
       if i:
           outfile.write(i)
```

Comment: Would appreciate if you share your code as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't written any code for this. The only reference I got was for taking paragraphs and converting them to list of words in a csv file.

Comment: You haven't written any code??? but you say `I have been able to create a list of words`

Comment: Yes...the question has been edited to reflect the code I used to generate a list of words.

Comment: This is how you created the csv file, but what did you code to get words from it and concatenate which is what this question is about?

Comment: I haven't been able to do that...I don't know how I can do that as I am just learning python and used the above code from other answers.

Comment: There are a gazillion questions available. Search: 1. How to read lines to list. 2. How to slice list. 3. How to join list.

Comment: Thanks...I will do that now. It was wrong of me to post a question like this without even attempting. I guess I got confused with different approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every line in your outfile.csv is a single word then this can be achieved simply in your second code sample.

```
with open("words.csv", encoding='UTF_8') as f:

    # Create a txt file (or what ever type you want)
    with open('sentences.txt', "a", encoding='UTF_8') as sent:

        # declare an empty list
        words = []

        # loop through lines
        for line in f:

            # add word to the word list
            # replace the line break with an empty string
            words.append(line.replace('\n', ''))

            # check to see if the list length is 15.
            if len(words) == 15:

                # join all words in list separated by a space
                # put a . at the end
                # add new line
                sent.write("{}.\n".format(" ".join(words)))
                # or without a .
                # sent.write("{}\n".format(" ".join(words)))

                # empty the list
                words = []
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: What if there is no need for a . (Dot)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. If you don't need the . then just remove it. See the new comment in the code with the . removed.